# Login Directly second time

Tags: java, android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I want to create Login page that user login only first time. When user want to use app second time they dont have to encounter login page. my code is here

```
 loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
     loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
     saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);

     if (saveLogin == true) {
            name.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
            pass.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));

        }

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             name1 = name.getText().toString();
             pass1 = pass.getText().toString();
           //new Thread (new Task()).start();
                loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
                loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", name1);
                loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", pass1);
                loginPrefsEditor.commit();
             new myAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

This code provides remember user's username and password but still when user want to use app second time they have to encounter login page.

How can i solve this problem.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What was the reason you unchecked my answer? What is the difference between my answer and the other one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this is you could design your app's architecture to set the main portion of your app as the the first activity to launch. Then the first thing that activity could do is check your shared preferences to see if the user has already authenticated themselves. If they haven't, launch the login activity and finish the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
if (saveLogin == true) {
            name1 = loginPreferences.getString("username", "");
            pass1 = loginPreferences.getString("password", "");
            new myAsyncTask().execute();

}
```

So when you have data in shared preferences you should login user by executing your AsyncTask